# How to pass data to Notification markdown in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, notifications, markdown

I am trying to pass variables to my notification markdown (instead of directly through the notification `toMail` method) because I need multiple action buttons. I want a user to be able to respond to a question posed in the email. Here is what I am trying in the notification markdown:

```php
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://myapp.dev/response/' . $event->id . '/' . $user->id . '/yes'])
Yes
@endcomponent

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'https://myapp.dev/response/' . $event->id . '/' . $user->id . '/no'])
No
@endcomponent
```

And here is my code for the notification itself:

```php
class eventAlert extends Notification
{
use Queueable;

public $event;
public $user;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Event $event, User $user)
{
    $this->event = $event;
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function toMail($notifiable)
{

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hey ' . $this->user->fn)
                ->line('There is an event today @ '. $this->event->edatetime->format('h:i A'))
                ->line($this->event->location)
                ->markdown('mail.notifications.eventalert');
}
```

But, I get an error for the scheduled job I am trying to run, that there is an undefined variable of event. I know that for `Mailable` classes you can use data passed through the constructor in the markdown itself, so I tried to change my variables to `public` from `protected` like it is supposed to be for `Mailable` classes, but this still doesn't work. How can I pass my variable data through to the notification markdown?

Comment: Where are you sending the notification in your application? are you passing in an `$event` object when you instantiate the notification?

Comment: I'm sending it through a `Job`. It checks if an event is today, and if it is, notifies all users of the event. Everything works fine until I try to add data like `$event->id` to the markdown itself. And yes, within the handle method of the Job, `$user->notify(new eventAlert($event, $user));`

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you assign it to a variable in the function, like:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $aux = $this->event;

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Hey ' . $this->user->fn)
                ->line('There is an event today @ '. $aux->edatetime->format('h:i A'))
                ->line($aux->location)
                ->markdown('mail.notifications.eventalert');
}
```

if this neither works, maybe the event is not being assigned properly.